# How to call a method inside a method, on click of a button? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, class, methods, admob

I created a method like this, and it contains some more methods. However, I do not know if I need the top method - `appNextCallAd()`. I would like some clarification on what is the best practice to call the `adLoaded()` method at the click of a button. Should I make this into a class? If yes, how? What is the best way, if I have to call `adLoaded()` from multiple activities? Thanks.

```
public void appNextCallAd() {
    // Get callback for ad loaded
    interstitial_Ad.setOnAdLoadedCallback(new OnAdLoaded() {
        @Override
        public void adLoaded() {
            interstitial_Ad.showAd();
        }
    });
    // Get callback for ad opened
    interstitial_Ad.setOnAdOpenedCallback(new OnAdOpened() {
        @Override
        public void adOpened() {

        }
    });
    // Get callback for ad clicked
    interstitial_Ad.setOnAdClickedCallback(new OnAdClicked() {
        @Override
        public void adClicked() {

        }
    });
    // Get callback for ad closed
    interstitial_Ad.setOnAdClosedCallback(new OnAdClosed() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {

        }
    });
    // Get callback for ad error
    interstitial_Ad.setOnAdErrorCallback(new OnAdError() {
        @Override
        public void adError(String error) {
            switch (error) {
                case AppnextError.NO_ADS:
                    Log.v("appnext", "no ads");
                    break;
                case AppnextError.CONNECTION_ERROR:
                    Log.v("appnext", "connection problem");
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.v("appnext", "other error");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the button click event;

```
private OnClickListener cancelBtn = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View V) {
            try {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
                Log.e("TEST2", ex.toString());
            }
           //How to call adLoaded() here?!
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you not just call interstitial_Ad.setOnAdOpenedCallback(new OnAdOpened() {... in the onClick method of your button?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the methods to set callbacks, just use "this" and implement the interfaces.

**Your class will be something like:**

```
class yourclass implements OnAdLoaded {
    public void appNextCallAd() {
    // Get callback for ad loaded
        interstitial_Ad.setOnAdLoadedCallback(this);
        ...
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void adLoaded() {
        ... do your stuff...
    }
```

then you will be able to call the method **adLoaded** from onClick. I suggest to do so:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
...
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.YOURBUTTONID:
            adLoaded();
        break;
}
```